# Homology of an interesting Lie algebra

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras, lie-algebra-cohomology

Let $U$ and $V$ be finite dimensional complex vector spaces (or perhaps graded vector spaces).

Let $E(U)$ be the "square zero extension" $\mathbb C \oplus U$, made into a commutative ring in such a way that $1 \in \mathbb C$ is the unit element and any two elements of $U$ multiply to zero.

Let $L(V)$ be the free Lie algebra on $V$.

Let $\mathfrak g$ be the Lie algebra $E(U) \otimes_{\mathbb C} L(V)$.

**Question:** What is the Lie algebra homology $H_\ast(\mathfrak g,\mathbb C)$? The answer will be some kind of polynomial functor in $U$ and $V$. (Or actually an analytic functor.)

Any ideas on how to approach such a calculation would be appreciated. It seems natural to study this via the Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence, either applied to the subalgebra $\mathbb C \otimes L(V) \subset \mathfrak g$ or the Lie ideal $U \otimes L(V) \subset \mathfrak g$, but I can't seem to calculate the answer from either one.

Comment: Why isn't this homology isomorphic to $\bigoplus_{n=0}^\infty H_*(L(V), Sym^n(L(V)\otimes U))$? Or is it that but it's just not useful?

Comment: @Gabriel thanks! I agree this is what you get from one of the spectral sequences (though Sym should be $\wedge$, I guess). But I don't know how to compute those groups!

Comment: Although it leads to an equivalent reformulation: if $S^\lambda(-)$ is a Schur functor, what is $H_\ast(L(V),S^\lambda(L(V)))$?

Comment: Since homology of the free lie algebra is the same as homology of the tensor algebra,  this is computed by a two term complex  $V \otimes S^{\lambda}(L(V)) \to S^{\lambda}(L(V))$.  When $S^\lambda$  is the identity functor we have that $H_0 = V$  and $H_1$ is the schur functor corresponding to the Whitehouse modules (see http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/transparencies/whouse.pdf).

Comment: @Phil Oh! That's really nice.

Comment: @Phil Could it be true in general that $H_0 $ of this 2-term complex is $S^\lambda(V) $? That would solve the problem completely!

Comment: @DanPetersen I think for $S^\lambda = Sym^2$  that in degree $3$  we have $V \otimes Sym^2 (V)  \to \wedge^2 V \otimes V$  which can't be surjective because the map can't hit $\wedge^3(V)$.

Comment: @DanPetersen But we can think of $H_0$ as being the "generators"  of $S^\lambda(L(V))$, so if this module is finitely generated, then in high degrees $H_0$ vanishes  and we can figure out the character of $H_1$.   Is this the case?